# How to buy short term and ultra short term bonds

Tags: investing, india, mutual-funds, short-term

I wanted to know how an individual can buy a short/ulta short term fund? Do i directly approach the agent/broker and deal through them?

Like for example , if i want to buy Franklin templeton's short term fund, how do i buy them? DO i call their agent/broker and deal with them? or is there any other way. Can i buy online?
I hope this is clearer than the first question.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome SahuKahn. Can you elaborate what you are asking for, the question is not clear. You can se the edit function to edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: you go to [Franklin Templeton's site](http://www.franklintempletonindia.com/) for India and open an account.

Or, you can go to a broker, like [Funds India](http://www.fundsindia.com/) that offers mutual funds from multiple fund companies. (Note: I just googled and found Funds India, I have no idea if they're good.)